# how do I properly express this 'rangeOfCharacter' statement using swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, range, swift3

I have some logic that allows me to listen to the editing of a textfield for invalid characters from a character set I created, obviously do to the rearrangement in swift 3 syntax, I get the following error:

`Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Range<Index>' with an argument list of type '(DefaultBidirectionalIndices<String.CharacterView>)`

on this line of code:

```
 if let _ = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: invalidCharacters, options: [], range:Range<String.Index>(string.characters.indices))
```

I've looked into the new API doc's but can't seem to find a correct formatting for this line in swift 3... any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to use `..<` operator to create your range. Note: If you want to check the whole string you can omit the options and range parameters.

```
if let _ = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: invalidCharacters, options: [], range: string.startIndex..<string.endIndex) {

}
```

Or simply:

```
if let _ = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: invalidCharacters) {

}
```

Comment: ha, i figured it was something this simple, being the removal of redundancy and slimming down the syntax in the new update.. gracias!